# Question about involutions and bijections

Tags: functions, proof-verification, involutions

I have seen a few times now that, any bijection on any set( finite, or not) can be written as a composition of two involution. However, it is usually said that this is a well known result.

However, my question is why is it so obvious? What is the basic proof of this that leads to it being considered trivial?

I am still not sure what the proof would be. Maybe something to do with orbits? I think probably would have to consider the finite and infinite cases apparently. Im just not sure.

I know this question has been asked before but I do not understand the answer given in the linked question. It still is not clear to me how to do such a thing.

Comment: yes, and it seems that it is only valid for a bijection from a set to itself